# how send offline notification in phonegap?

Tags: phonegap-build

how send offline notification in phone gap.? please anyone know about offline notification.please help me. It works properly even if online but I wanted to get notification after app is closed.It gives notification Only for 3-5 hours after app is closed but I wanted to show them repeating 10 times per day for 10 days offline.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Cordova Local-Notification Plugin to send offline push notification https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications